# dynamic ImageView TranslateAnimation

Tags: android, animation, imageview

I have images that need to appear from one location a user clicks, and move to another location the user clicks.  I think the issue I am having is how to initially place the ImageView at a given absolute X,Y (my main view root layout is the default LinearLayout).  This is what I'm currently trying, the animation runs but is not visible (after 1000ms the end function is indeed called).

```
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(mainActivity);

    String imgname = "drawable/animImg";
    int imgId = act.getResources().getIdentifier(imgname, "drawable", act.getPackageName());
    iv.setImageDrawable(act.getResources().getDrawable(imgId));

    /*didn't seem to help
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    ((ViewGroup)mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout)).addView(iv,lp);
    */

    int[] srcxy = new int[2];
    src.getLocationInWindow(srcxy);
    int[] destxy = new int[2];
    dest.getLocationInWindow(destxy);

    TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation( Animation.ABSOLUTE, srcxy[0], Animation.ABSOLUTE, destxy[0], Animation.ABSOLUTE, srcxy[1], Animation.ABSOLUTE, destxy[1]);
    translateAnimation.setDuration(1000);
    translateAnimation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());

    translateAnimation.setAnimationListener( new MyAnimationListenener( c, src, dest, this ) );
    iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    iv.startAnimation(translateAnimation);
```

So is there a way for me to specify that I want to first position the ImageView at srcxy[0],srcxy[1] before I animate?  Or am I even going about this in the right way?

Answer (score 0):

You can't place an ImageView to a x,y position if it's contained in a LinearLayout: as the name indicates, LinearLayout is used to display elements sequencely in horizontal or vertical order. I think you have to use FrameLayout. If you look at [this example](http://myandroidwidgets.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/DragDrop/src/com/beanie/example/Home.java) you can find a the piece of code that reaches your goal.